# How to build a Video Streaming Server with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming

I was trying to build an application, like Eros Now or Hotstar, that can serve/play local video for the user. I am using ivy-videojs pluging for Frontend (ember), but not sure how to serve video content through rails.

Can anyone help me to stream content from Rails or to choose proper technology stack for it?

Comment: I found nginx as a solution

Comment: user7195772 Can you please send me the link of resources that you found?